# xcode tableview messing textfield data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I got a prototype table with a custom Cell and inside this cell a textField.

My array of cells is a large one, so when I scroll the table, the cells need to be recreated.

Testing, when I scroll the text that was in the txt field of 1 cell goes to another, keyboard types change and everything gets messed-up!

CODE:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"customTableCell";

    customTableViewCell *cell = (customTableViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[customTableViewCell alloc]
                initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                reuseIdentifier:nil];
    }

    // Configuration
    cell.lblName.text = [self.pfFields objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]];

    cell.txtType = [self.pfTypes objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]];

    cell.mySql = [self.pfSql objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]];


    //cell.txtField.delegate = self;

    if ([[self.pfTypes objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] isEqualToString: @"n"]) {
        [cell.txtField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad];
    } else if ([[self.pfTypes objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] isEqualToString: @"m"]) {
        [cell.txtField setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be sure to set all properties of a cell in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, because a given cell can be reused at any time by the controller.

To prevent the text from jumping around, you need to set `cell.txtField.text` to the appropriate `NSString` loaded from your cell's backing object.  Similarly, you should always set the `keyboardType` every time (I assume that there are cases besides just `n` and `m`).  Setting the properties every time ensures that you get the correct display regardless of how the reused cell was previously configured.

Comment: I fixed the keyboard, but the textField is still a problem... How can I keep a NSString updated with the textField text, since it's a prototype table?

Comment: Since you already have some backing objects (`pfFields`, `pfTypes`, and `pfSql`, I would consolidate them into one model object that corresponds to a single cell, and then have a text property on that object.

Comment: You would use something similar to `[self.someArrayOfModels objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` and then use that object's properties.

Comment: Is there a way so I can access a object like pfFields from inside the cell?

Comment: You can expose a property on the cell and then pass in the entire backing object.  At this point you might want to accept this answer and open a new question with your code so far.